# Bash cannot act as nobody and nogroup?

Tags: bash, shell, users, privileges

I have a log file that was created by `nobody`:`nogroup`, which is activity being logged to, I wanted to emulate adding a message to that log file.
My first thought was to:

```
$ sudo su nobody
This account is currently not available.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a way simpler solution, just run: `su -s /bin/bash nobody` (replace `/bin/bash` with the shell of your choice).

The `This account is currently not available.` error is due to the fact that `nobody` user default shell is `/usr/sbin/nologin`, `su -s` force the system to use another shell.

Answer (score 10):

An email thread:

- http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2002-September/001225.html
- http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2002-September/001226.html

.. points out that `sudo -u nobody [cmd ...]` can be used:

(Combined with the trick of [How to append to a file as sudo](https://superuser.com/a/136653/309066))

```
echo "Hello World" | sudo -u nobody tee -a /tmp/logfile.log
```